# VBA Run Time Error: The requested Header Was Not Found

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

I am using this code to fetch historical data from Yahoo Finance. This was working fine, until I started receiving this error:

VBA Run Time Error:'2147012746 (80072f76)': The requested Header Was Not Found.

When I debug the error, it seems it s occuring on this line:

cookie = Split(.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"), ";")(0)

Any suggestion?

```
Sub getCookieCrumb(crumb As String, cookie As String, validCookieCrumb As Boolean)

Dim i As Integer
Dim str As String
Dim crumbStartPos As Long
Dim crumbEndPos As Long
Dim objRequest

validCookieCrumb = False

For i = 0 To 5  'ask for a valid crumb 5 times
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup?s=bananas", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send
        .waitForResponse (10)
        cookie = Split(.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"), ";")(0)
        'crumbStartPos = InStr(1, .ResponseText, """CrumbStore"":{""crumb"":""", 
        vbBinaryCompare) + Len("""CrumbStore"":{""crumb"":""")
        crumbStartPos = InStrRev(.ResponseText, """crumb"":""") + 9
        crumbEndPos = crumbStartPos + 11 'InStr(crumbStartPos, .ResponseText, """", 
        vbBinaryCompare)
        crumb = Mid(.ResponseText, crumbStartPos, crumbEndPos - crumbStartPos)
        'Sheets("Parameters").Range("C30") = crumbStartPos
        'Sheets("Parameters").Range("C31") = crumbEndPos
        'Sheets("Parameters").Range("c32") = crumb
        End With
    
    If Len(crumb) = 11 Then 'a valid crumb is 11 characters long
        validCookieCrumb = True
        Exit For
    End If:
    
    'If i = 5 Then ' no valid crumb
    ' validCookieCrumb = False
    'End If
     Next i

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the use of cookie and crumb entirely in your Yahoo! Finance data scrape request. So, don't call getCookieCrumb at all.

Then modify your call to call to getYahooFinanceData (or whatever you called your sub) to eliminate the cookie and crumb attribute.

Your tickerURL (or whatever you called it) will also drop the cookie and crumb from the end. Just use ticker, start and end period, interval, and event.